# Why can't I install the midnight commander on Debian?

Tags: debian, package-management, mc

The midnight commander is not installed on my Debian Linux, so I tried to download it.

I ran `apt-get install mc` in the terminal but it says `the pack is not found`. I did this task as root and the internet connection is perfect. I don't know why I can't download and install the MC. Does anybody know?

My `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
#

# deb cdrom: [Debian GNU/Linux 7.6.0 _Wheezy_ - Offical amd64 CD Binary-1 20140712-14:11]/ wheezy main

deb cdrom: [Debian GNU/Linux 7.6.0 _Wheezy_ - Offical amd64 CD Binary-1 20140712-14:11]/wheezy main

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/update main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main

# wheezy-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
# A networl mirror was not selected during install. The following entries
# are provided as examples, but you should amend them as appropriate
# for your mirror of choice.
#
# deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main
# deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`. The command you tried should have worked so you probably have a problem with your sources.

Comment: I can't ran this. It says the permission is refused. I did this as root.

Comment: Perhaps running `apt-get update` before running `apt-get install` might also help. Also, `apt-cache search mc` might also cast light into your trouble.

Comment: Please add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` to your question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing the main Debian repositories, your sources only point to the security repo. Uncomment the last lines in `/etc/apt/sources/list`. Change this:

```
# deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main
# deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main
```

to this:

```
 deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main
 deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main
```

That, however, will give you access to the generic repos, you will get much better performance if you choose one of your local mirrors. So, either choose one close to you from [this list](https://www.debian.org/mirror/list) or use [`netselect-apt`](http://www.debianadmin.com/howto-select-fastest-mirror-in-debian.html):

```
sudo apt-get install netselect-apt
sudo netselect-apt -n wheezy
sudo cp ./sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list
```

No matter what you choose to do, remember to refresh your sources by running

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: I don't think `wheezy-updates` is the same as `wheezy`, the main repository.

Comment: @jw013 so it isn't, thanks, I'd just copied it from the OP.

Comment: For those wondering there is a typo in `sudo netyselect-apt -n wheezy` should be with out the `y`

Comment: @EugenevanderMerwe good catch, thanks! Answer corrected.

Answer (score 3):

To utilize the Debian redirector (http://http.debian.net/)...

> The redirector uses the geo and network location of the user and the mirrors, the architecture of the requested files, IP address family, the availability and freshness of the mirrors, and a few other things.

Using main, contrib, and non-free with the redirector, `/etc/apt/sources.list`  looks like this:

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib

# wheezy-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib
```

Update: `sudo apt-get update`
Install mc: `sudo apt-get install  mc`